# CSS selector hop 1 element after 2 elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

So, I want some CSS values only on certain elements, like this:

```
2,3, 5,6, 8,9, 11,12 etc. (numbers being the elements)
```

I have googled alot, but I just can't find how to do it.

Comment: Can you add some code, so we can see what you have tried so far?

Comment: Well, I have tried nothing, because I knew it could be done with :nth-child, but didn't know how. Couldn't find it on the internet either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all elements but not those who are `:nth-child(3n + 1)`

```
:not(:nth-child(3n + 1))
```

so as to exclude elements in position `1,4,7,10`...

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyVMpE)

Comment: thanks man! It works perfectly, and is a bit shorter then the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nth-child` selector with `3n` and `3n+2` as the arguments. `3n` selects all elements that are numbered 3, 6, 9, 12... whereas the `3n+2` selects elements that are numbered 2, 5, 8, 11..

```css
li:nth-child(3n+2),
li:nth-child(3n) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
</ul>
```